# Comparative religion textbooks from a Catholic viewpoint

Tags: catholicism, resource-request, comparative-religion

Most Catholic text books about religion are about Catholicism, I asked my high-school aged daughter what she wants to study next year for religion class and she said she's like to know about other religions.  I'm having a hard time finding these kinds of books.

Most popular authors will write a book condemning this or that other religion, but I just want one that honestly compares them all without being wishywashy about which is better.  Otherwise, I think I'd have to piece together about a hundred books.

Comment: John Dickson's [A Spectator's Guide to World Religions](https://www.amazon.com/Spectators-Guide-World-Religions-introduction-ebook/dp/B075TDVYWB/) isn't specifically Catholic, but is good in the Mere Christianity sort of way. It aims to present Hinduism, Buddhism, Judaism, Christianity, and Islam fairly in ways their adherents would support, and also lets each explain what issues they have with Christianity, rather than just giving a Christian critique of each. The publisher put up the [Hinduism section](https://www.cepstore.com.au/IdaProductQAYW?Id=01t0K000005dqk0QAA) as a sample.

Comment: Huston Smith's book The World's Religions is old but a classic.

Comment: @MattGutting thanks for the suggestion, I ordered that one (with a workbook) for a few bucks.  Doesn't look like Huston Smith has a Catholic worldview though.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a good apologetics book, because these are designed to refute the errors of false religions / belief systems and show how the Catholic religion is the only true one, e.g.:

- [*Catholic Apologetics: God, Christianity, and the Church*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6960) by Fr. John Laux
- [*The Principles of Catholic Apologetics*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3024) by Fr. T. J. Walshe

This more recent one compares Catholic theology and philosophy to that of other, non-Catholic belief systems (including even Eastern, Indian thought):

- [*The Way toward Wisdom: An Interdisciplinary and Intercultural Introduction to Metaphysics*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=2920) by [Benedict Ashley, O.P.](http://www.morec.com/nature/ashley.htm)
  <sub>Fr. Benny had [a very interesting life](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4064), being an ex-Marxist before his conversion.</sub>

A classic comparing Catholic doctrine to Protestant/Lutheran doctrine is:

- [*Symbolism, or, Exposition of the doctrinal differences between Catholics and Protestants as evidenced by their symbolical writings*](https://archive.org/details/symbolismorexpos00mhuoft) by Möhler, Johann Adam, 1796-1838
  <sub>"Symbol" in the sense of "creed" (σύμβολον, *symballein*, means a collection: "[It is from its being a collection of maxims of faith that the symbol [*The Greek {symballein}] takes its name.](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS001.html#SSQ1A9THEP1)"</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I have 3 recommendations:

1. First, gathered in this one volume, [But Not Philosophy: Seven Introductions to Non-Western Thought](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0739102907) provides useful and thought-provoking introductions to 7 major "schools" of non-Western thought: Mesopotamian, ancient African, Hindu, Confucian, Buddhist, Islamic, and North American Indian. George Anastaplo (the author) studies ancient literary epics and legal codes and examines religious traditions and systems of thought, providing detailed references to authoritative histories and commentators.
2. Secondly, to find the greatest division in the entire history of religions, either of these two books:

   - [Truth in Religion: The Plurality of Religions and the Unity of Truth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0020641400) by Mortimer Adler OR
   - [Reason, Faith, and the Struggle for Western Civilization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F6P81DX) by Samuel Gregg.
3. Thirdly  --and this is is a wildcard -- [The Slain God: Anthropologists and the Christian Faith](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198757425) by Timothy Larsen.
   This will show you that the bias and the lack of honest comparison is an epidemic of the scholars you are depending upon.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm definitely going to check out that Mortimer Adler book.